# Populate a table with data from a database using a loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have quite a few tables on my site, each of which contains two columns: A title and a value from the SQL database. I am currently putting the data in the table using:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class = "item">House</td>
<td class = "req"><?php $row_buyerdetails['tod_house']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class = "item">Bungalow</td>
<td class = "req"><?php $row_buyerdetails['tod_bung']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This seems like a long winded way of creating the table (especially as I will have alot more rows than this and quite a few separate tables). Also if I want to make a change to the class name for example, Id have to change every row in every table! There must be a way of putting the 'item' and the 'req' pairs in an array, and then creating a loop which makes the table, populates with the data from the database and assigns the classes? Im new to PHP so cant work out how to do this!

---

### EDIT

The table code above will create the following table:

[image]

The tables layout is how I want it. However, i dont want to type out every line of code, I want to put the type of dwelling (with a class of 'item') and the result from the database (with a class of 'req') in an array, and then loop through this array to create the table rather than typing out every `<tr>` and `<td>` for every row and every table. I just dont know the technique in PHP to loop through and create the different tags, insert the data into them, and assign the different `<td>` a class each!

Comment: show example what exactly want ! . difficult to read your explanation .

Comment: im not getting what actual you need, but u can use loop above <table> so that it will print/display till your query will be execute...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though your question is not quite clear, I am suggesting a solution from what I understood.

You can use [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop. First you store the title that you want to show on page("House", "Bungalow",..) in an array associated with the titles from your database table.

So it will be like

```
<?php $arrTitles = array("tod_house"=>"House", "tod_bung"=>"Bungalow"); ?>
```

And your table code should be like

```
<table>
<?php
   foreach($row_buyerdetails as $k=>$v) {
?>
     <tr>
       <td class = "item"><?php echo $arrTitles[$k]; ?></td>
       <td class = "req"><?php echo $v; ?></td>
     </tr>
<?php
   }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - its close to working! The new issue is the loop looks through the $row_buyerdetails array (which contains ~50 items). Where they match up to a value in the $arrTitles array it works fine, but where there is no entry in the $arrTitles it still creates a table row but puts "undefined index" in there. How do I make sure that it only loops through the values in the $arrTitles array rather than the values in the $row_buyerdetails array?

Comment: Sorted, just had to change the array that looped from the big $row_buyerdetails to the small $arrTitles as this was the one that determined the size of the table (obviously changing the echo arrays accordingly too). Thankyou for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view helper function that will accept an array and return a table. Take note of the usage of [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

```
function create_table(array $rows, $headingClassName = '') {
    $buffer = '<table>';
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $buffer .= '<tr><td';
        if ($headingClassName) {
            $buffer .= ' class="' . htmlspecialchars($headingClassName) . '"';
        }
        $buffer .= '>' . htmlspecialchars($row['name']) . '</td><td';
        if ($row['class']) {
            $buffer .= ' class="' . htmlspecialchars($row['class']) . '"';
        }
        $buffer .= '>' . htmlspecialchars($row['value']) . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $buffer .= '</table>';

    return $buffer;
}
```

Example of how your code may look after receiving information from your database:

```
// row received from database (column => value)
$row_buyerdetails = array(
    'tod_house' => 1,
    'tod_bung'  => 1,
    'tod_flat'  => 1,
    'tod_conv'  => 1,
    'tod_farm'  => 0,
    'tod_hold'  => 0,
    'tod_plot'  => 1
);

// describe the headings for the rows from the database
$headings = array(
    'tod_house' => 'House',
    'tod_bung'  => 'Bungalow',
    'tod_flat'  => 'Flat',
    'tod_conv'  => 'Barn Conversion',
    'tod_farm'  => 'Farm',
    'tod_hold'  => 'Small Holding',
    'tod_plot'  => 'Building Plot'
);

// convert integers to yes/no and add the req class. you can do this more elegantly
// by modifying the create_table method which would remove the need for this loop.
array_walk($row_buyerdetails, function (&$value, $key) use ($headings) {
    $value = array(
        'class' => 'req',
        'name'  => $headings[$key],
        'value' => $value ? 'yes' : 'no'
    );
});
```

Lastly you can output the table in your view:

```
<?php echo create_table($row_buyerdetails, 'item'); ?>
```

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers. This is a far more useful answer as it allows me to pass the array to the function for any table I want. However the accepted answer does do what I asked in the question so better stick with my first choice! Great code though, thankyou! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
foreach ($results as $row) {
echo '<tr>';

echo '<td class = "item">House</td>';
echo '<td class = "req">'. $row_buyerdetails['tod_house'] .'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class = "item">Bungalow</td>';
echo '<td class = "req">'. $row_buyerdetails['tod_bung'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
</table>
```

Comment: @mathielo take it easy man, if he doesn't get it , I will explain it in more details, thanks for downvoting